# How do I create an array from a select statement?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

This seems easy enough but I can't get the format correct. I have some rows like this:

```
alias  # is character varying(20) column-type
------
Bob2
Judy5
Jane6
Erica7
```

I'd like to aggregate all these rows into 1 array:

```
[Bob2, Judy5, Jane6, Erica7]
```

I can only seem to get:

```
{(Bob2), (Judy5), (Jane6), (Erica7)}

SELECT array_agg(r) FROM (
  SELECT name FROM mytable
  ) r
```

How can I get it to the format I'd like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are aggregating a *set* not a column (because `r` in your query refers to the derived table, not to a column). All you need to do is:

```
select array_agg(name) 
from my_table;
```

Or if you insist on having the derived table:

```
SELECT array_agg(r.name) 
FROM (
  SELECT name 
  FROM mytable
) r
```

Comment: ahh, I see. Why does it give me "{1,2,3}" rather than "[1,2,3]"?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
create table test(alias varchar(20));
insert into test values ('Bob2'), ('Judy5'), ('Jane6'), ('Erica7');
select replace(replace(array_agg(alias)::varchar, '{', '['), '}', ']') from test

Result:
[Bob2,Judy5,Jane6,Erica7]
```